# MySQL REGEXP repeating characters

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

How can I find strings with individual repeating characters (for example 3 times)?

This works but I don't want rewrite every alpha characters (a,b,c,d,e...):

... REGEXP '(a){3}|(b){3}|(c){3}|(d){3}|(e){3}|(f){3}...' ...

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

```
r = '(\w)\1{2}`
```

finds any alphanumeric character that is repeated (at least) three times, matching the first three.

Comment: If you want any repeating sequence of at least three alphabetic characters (no numerals), use `([:alpha:])\1{2,}`

Answer (score 0):

How about repeating a capture group?

```
r = '([abc])\1\1'
```

Comment: That will find aaa bbb or ccc.

Comment: @dj_segfault - That's what I interpreted the question to want - repeated individual characters, so in 'asvvaaababbb' there would be two matches - 'aaa' and 'bbb' because those characters are repeated three times.

Comment: fix the question with "individual" characters ;)

Comment: @user476918: I reread the question and I think you're right.  I apologize and reversed my vote.

Comment: i understood the question as same as @g.d.d.c, and just wanted to give:`([a-zA-Z])\1\1`, saw his answer. :(

Answer (score -2):

```
'(abc){3}'
```

Example:

```
> echo 'bbbabcabcabcaaabbbccc' | egrep -o '(abc){3}'
abcabcabc
```

Comment: this will find only 'abc' in sequences :(

Comment: OP asked for MYSQL regexp.